# Prevent incoming connections

Tags: networking, irc

My network has some problems with incoming connections. Surfing is fine, but I want to use an IRC-Chat. I tried to use webchat (either the webchat of the server, or mibbit), but I still get incoming connections (proxyscan). Is there a possibility to prevent these incoming connections or a webclient, that "catches" these?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Popups from a firewall? A tiny amount of incoming connection attempts can do absolutely no harm when there's nothing that would accept them.

Comment: @grawity: It's a crashing router I don't have access to.

Comment: If you block those incoming connections then those services wouldn't actually work they are required.

Answer (score 0):

If you prevent any incoming connections, many internet apps would not work. IRC servers are known, for example, for

- Scanning any connecting user for open proxies
- any file download using DCC / XDCC starts from SENDING party (you can't download, you are being uploaded requested, or not, item)
- identd on port 113 (havent had this rule on firewall lately, maybe it's not used anymore...)

So if you get any warning from a firewall when using IRC client, choose one you can trust and whitelist it.

Comment: Alternatively, blacklist it. For the proxy scan, it's *expected* that there will be no proxies running. For identd, a rejected connection is also okay on most networks. (What isn't okay is *silently dropped* connections, where the IRC server has to wait many seconds for a timeout...)